# Eliminate the xml-code from xml-files

Tags: regex, xml, powershell

I want to get rid of the xml-code from within more than 100 xml-files.
I want to use PowerShell. Here is one sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../../../helpproject.xsl" ?><topic 
template="Default" lasteditedby="liliya" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org
/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../..
/../helpproject.xsd">

<title translate="true">Passwörter verwalten</title>

<body>
<header>
  <para styleclass="Heading1"><text styleclass="Heading1" 
translate="true">Passwörter verwalten</text></para>
</header>
<para styleclass="Normal"><table styleclass="container" rowcount="3" 
colcount="2" style="width:970px;">
  <tr style="vertical-align:top">
    <td style="width:50%;">
      <para styleclass="H1"><text styleclass="H1" 
translate="true">Passwörter verwalten</text></para>
    </td>
    <td style="width:50%;">
      <para styleclass="Image"><image src="manage_passwords.PNG" 

scale="100.00%" styleclass="Image"><title translate="true">Passwörter 
verwalten</title></image></para>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table></para>
<para styleclass="txt"/>
```

In Notepad++ after regex of <.+?> and ^\s+ I see just the text!

With this script I copy the originals (to leave them unchanged) to a single folder and then O just want to eliminate the xml-tags:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\cas\Documents\Wurzel_XML\" -Recurse |
Where-Object Name -like "*.xml" | 
Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Users\cas\Documents\check_xml\"

$newText = ($newText -replace "<.*?>", "").trim()|?{$_ -ne ''} 
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\cas\Documents\check_xml\" |
    Set-Content -Value $newText
```

But after that all the files are completely empty?

I previously tried

```
$newText = ($newText -replace "(?ms)^\s+<.*?</.*?>", "")
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\cas\Documents\check_xml\" |
    Set-Content -Value $newText
```

with the same result.
What do I wrong with that Regex?
Thanks in advance,
Gooly

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Can you provide examples of what your input looks like, and what you expect your output to look like? Properly-structured "XML files" contain "XML code"; if you remove the XML code from an XML file, you _will_ have an empty file.

Comment: Regular expressions **are not** the appropriate tool to edit XML content.

Comment: Completely agree, it's [a terrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/712649)

Comment: *No matter how many times we say it, they won't stop coming every day... every hour even. It is a lost cause...* --- This link gets posted 100s of times every day, yet we still see an **endless** stream of "how can I parse XML with regex" questions :(

Comment: Maybe StackOverflow should add a prompt, that asks all users mentioning "regex" and "xml/html" in a question to read that answer before clicking "submit".

Comment: I am translating text of the xml-files I am not editing the xml-code! I need to proof read the text that will later appear elsewhere. The text is just 20%-25% of the size of the xml-files. So I just need the pure text to be able to read what other later will read. They don't see the xml-code either! 
But if you don't like the idea just help me to that crazy thing - deal?

Comment: I tried to add xml-code but I wasn't able! The site knows css html javascript but no xml

Comment: @gooly gladly, but as Jeff Zeitlin mentioned we'll need a bit more information - please show us a sample input and ouput at least. If the xml doesn't render, please [leave it in your question anyways, and we'll help you edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543131/eliminate-the-xml-code-from-xml-files) - don't post it in comments

Comment: @TomLord where is that link - I haven seen any

Comment: @gooly once again, please [edit the full xml into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543131/eliminate-the-xml-code-from-xml-files#) - select it all and press `Ctrl + K` to format as code

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: Well in Notepad+ I just do two Regex-replacements: <.+?> and ^\s+ and I see the pure text - the problem is that I don't want to do it separately for more that 100 xml-files!

Comment: @gooly for the third time: please [add the sample xml to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48543131/edit) if you want qualified help

Comment: That's not a valid xml document

Comment: The Files I am dealing with look like that. From one of them I took the first part deleted some parts in the middle and left the last part.

Comment: So you mean to say that actually all of your XML files are invalid? Because what you posted most definitely is not valid XML.

Comment: @gooly The link was in the comment directly above mine. It's also shown in the top right of this page, under the sub-heading: "Linked". *Do not use regex to edit XML.*

Answer (score 1):

## [***Do Not Use Regular Expression Processing To Parse HTML, XHTML, or XML***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/712649)

PowerShell has cmdlets that can be used to process XML, and the techniques that can be used with it have been discussed in many places (See [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Powershell+XML)). If you read your files as structured XML files, and then use the [`Select-XML` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-5.1) with appropriate [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) queries, you can extract the information you need, reliably - provided that your XML is well-formed in the first place.

Comment: All the examples deal with the nodes (structure,info,tabulars,..) - but this is not what I need - I just want to eliminate the xml-stuff from the xml file - I want to treat the as simple text files as they (or their copies) aren't used as xml-files at all.

Comment: Then you're not understanding what XML is, or how it works - because you appear to want to extract CONTENT from nodes that have it - which is possible when processing XML with `Select-XML` - look at the MS Docs link I gave you in the answer. One of the examples specifically shows how to do it.

Comment: Do you mean this one: Select-Xml -Content $Xml -XPath "//edition" | foreach {$_.node.InnerXML} ?
Well I don't know the name of all nodes of more than 100 xml-files and without it I am asked to enter the name of a node :(

Comment: Yes, that's the example that I was thinking of. I haven't checked in detail, but I'm quite sure there's a way to select any element that has content, which is what you'd want to do.

Comment: @gooly `([xml](Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.xml')).DocumentElement.InnerText` will give you the raw text of an XML file, without the need to know any particular node name. Provided your XML is actually valid, that is.

Comment: Thanks - but how can I loop through more that 100 xm-files replacing their content by: ([xml](Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.xml')).DocumentElement.InnerText ?

Comment: That is a completely different question but essentially ***foreach($file in Get-ChildItem PATHTOFOLDER){}***